# PHP: return the minimum value of an array per key

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$array[] = $row;
$array[$i]["distance"] = distance($row["latitude"], .. etc ); //distance function
```

I tried to get the minimum using uasort():

```
function sort_by_orden ($a, $b) {
return $a["distance"] > $b["distance"];
}
uasort ($array, 'sort_by_orden');
```

And he returned what he needed .. calculate the smallest value for distance between the objects in the array.

But I have the following problem with the way I can return the data:

```
Array
    (
        [3] => Array
            (
                [name] => ALEJANDRO m
                [ID] => 220
                [road] => Villalobos
                [distance] => 2.9
            )

        [2] => Array
            (

                [name] => ALEJANDRO m  
                [ID] => 219
                [road] => Diego Velásquez
                [distance] => 3.4
            )

        [1] => Array
            (

                [name] => javier mank
                [ID] => 220
                [road] => Villalobos
                [distance] => 4.6
            )

        [0] => Array
            (

                [name] => javier mank
                [ID] => 219
                [road] => Diego Velásquez
                [distance] => 5.2
            )

    )
```

As you can see, the array was organized by distance, but what I need is to return the value min away, for each ID.

In such a way that when I need to consult who is closest to "ID" I will return only the lowest value of distance, for example:

*ID = 220 return:*

```
[name] => ALEJANDRO m
[road] => Villalobos
[distance] => 2.9
```

And I just need to get the lowest value of each ID, the truth that I have no idea where to start.

Said wildly should be layers of knowing the lowest distance according to your ID, if I consult the ID 219 or 220 would answer the lowest distance .. and that's where I have no idea how to start. How do I make that comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it you only need to reset the keys with array_values then use $arr[0].

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
var_dump($arr[0]);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
     [name] => ALEJANDRO m
     [ID] => 220
     [road] => Villalobos
     [distance] => 2.9
)
```

---

Wild guess.

```
// Get all ids from array
$ids = array_column($arr, "id");
foreach(array_unique($$ids) as $id){
    // Create new associative array on id for later use.
    $new[$id] = array_values(array_intersect_keys($arr, array_intersect($ids, [$id])));
}

$find = 219;
var_dump($new[$find]);
// This returns all 219 sorted with [0] being the closest and end() the furthest away.
```

Comment: Your answer has helped me because it is possible to correct your indexes but it is not enough to solve the problem .. the problem in question is like knowing who is closer to ID 219 and not the 220 for example? How do I make that comparison? It is assumed that my code should return the lowest distance according to your identification ID.

Thinking wildly you should compare the distance of the trips according to your ID, and if you would like to consult that, just call by your ID and return the lowest value.

This is my problem.

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about. I'm sure I can solve it for you but sadly I can't understand what you mean

Comment: @LanPunkk look at my edited code, does that solve your porblem?

Comment: thanks for the answer was what I was looking for, I have to review many times the array functions that I am in -2 jeje

Comment: Ok. I will give you a better answer tomorrow. The code I posted does the job but is a bit slower than needed. The other code I will post tomorrow is a bit more complex and I'm in bed right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure 100% that this is what you want, but check this out.
It will return the array ordered by ID and by distance.

```
$array = array(
    [
    'ID' => 220,
    'distance' => 5.9
    ],[
    'ID' => 220,
    'distance' => 2.9
    ],[
    'ID' => 221,
    'distance' => 3.9
    ],[
    'ID' => 220,
    'distance' => 3.9
    ],[
    'ID' => 221,
    'distance' => 1.9
    ],);

// Here is where the magic is done.
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'ID'),  SORT_ASC,
                array_column($array, 'distance'), SORT_ASC,
                $array);
```

And the output will be:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(220)
    ["distance"]=>
    float(2.9)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(220)
    ["distance"]=>
    float(3.9)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(220)
    ["distance"]=>
    float(5.9)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(221)
    ["distance"]=>
    float(1.9)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(221)
    ["distance"]=>
    float(3.9)
  }
}
```

If you only want the ID's with the minimum distance, you can change the order to SORT_DESC and use this:

```
foreach($array as $element) {
    $hash = $element['ID'];
    $unique_array[$hash] = $element;
}
```

This will create a new array with the ID's with the lowest distance.

If this is not what you want, clarify me a little the problem so I can give you the correct solution. :)

Comment: thank you for the answer was what I was looking for.

Comment: Welcome @LanPunkk! :)